# Is It possible to add dll refrence of c# file into Labwindow

Tags: labwindows

Is It possible to add dll refrence of c# file into Labwindow.

Hi I want to use dotnet program written in c# in Labwindow/cvi in c language is it possible or not??

Answer (score 0):

Your question poses other questions, but in a nutshell, Yes, you can use a .net/c# .dll within CVI.  The easiest way is to include a header file and .lib generated for that .dll.  The CVI project should compile/build and run.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible
on help>Contents>index> dll you will find **Exporting DLL Functions and Variables**
there is 3 way to do so , but i suguest " Using the Export Qualifier Method "

best regards

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).